# How to send nodejs binary response through nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

Sorry in advance for the (probably) incorrect terminology used in this question.

I have a small nodejs api that dynamically generates pdfs and responds with a buffer object. The relevant part that returns the response should be this:

```
        res.write(buffer,'binary')
        res.end(null, 'binary')
```

It properly returns the pdf when running the app directly on localhost.

However, when running the same code on my server, it returns some gibberish instead:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ)
/Creator (þÿ)
/Producer (þÿ�Q�t� �5�.�5�.�1)
/CreationDate (D:20171020141355)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
[... and so on]
```

The same is the case when running the app locally but connecting to the correct port on the server. Since the code is the same, I assume the problem may be how nginx handles the data. Here's the (probably) relevant bit of the current nginx setup:

```
   location /my/api {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:1111;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering on;

    }
```

Thanks for any advise on how to fix this!

**Edit:** changing the the node response above to the following fixes the problem. Thanks for the help in the comments!

```
        res.type('application/pdf')
        res.send(buffer)
```

Comment: `res.type(type)` and `res.send(buffer)` should work out of the box. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Have you correctly set the `Content-Type` header of your response ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev do you mean to use `res.type(type)` `res.send(buffer)` instead of `res.write(buffer,'binary')` `res.end(null, 'binary')` ?

Comment: @citivin Yes. That's what I meant. Use `application/pdf` for `type`.

Comment: @Techniv would that be `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')` for this case?

Comment: Yes. Check also the effective value of the header in your server and nginx responses.

Comment: @BrahmaDev that fixes the problem. Cheers!